# import a lib maven into npm package.json

Tags: maven, gradle, npm, kotlin

I use gradle to build a kotlin multiplatform lib (i use -surprise- the org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform !!)
I build it to mobile, java and js

My issue is that this plugin publish only into maven repository(even the js output lib !), and I want to also use my lib into a node js/npm project.

Is there a way to tell my package.json to search into a maven repo?

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies can be precised in a number of ways in `package.json`. The most simple and widely used way is the following:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "<package-name>": "<version-range>",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
}
```

But there are actually [many ways](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) to include dependencies beyond that. Replace the version range by either one of the following:

- Tarball URL of the package
- Git URL of the package, example: `git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/cli.git#v1.0.27`
- Github of the package, example: `expressjs/express`
- Local paths, example: `file:../foo/bar`

I'm pretty sure one of these four options can be tweaked to include a dependency from a maven repo.

Comment: I didn't know .jar could contain .js files! In any case - I'd advise you to download the JS lib locally and include it as a local path

Comment: the gradle build that I use is multiplateform, but put the js file in a jar (gradle and maven are able to manipulate js into jar file)